# String replace isn't working for some russian characters

Tags: android, xiaomi

For some reason I need to replace russian letter "Ё" with "Е". So I wrote this simple code

```
someString = someString.toLowerCase().replace("ё", "е");
```

It's working perfectly fine on emulators and most of my devices, except Xiaomi Redmi 9a. The app doesn't replace "ё" on Xiaomi at all.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xiaomi Redmi 9a doesn't use russian letter "Ё", it uses "Ë"! :) It's latin letter "E" with diaeresis. I don't know is it because of keyboard or something else.

So we need to change code to this

```
// The first character of pattern is russian Ё, the second is latin E with diaeresis. 
// Some Xiaomi devices use the second variant instead of russian letter
someString = someString.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[ёë]", "е");
```

or this

```
someString = someString.toLowerCase().replace("ё", "е").replace("ë", "е");
```